# Group on field, get grouped ids as an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT field_name
FROM table
GROUP BY field_name
```

The above will get me the distinct set of `field_name`.

What I would like is the distinct set of `field_name` and in the next column an array of all the ids which has that `field_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_agg()` if you want a true array:

```
select field_name, array_agg(id)
from the_table
group by field_name;
```

or `string_agg()` if you just want a comma separated list:

```
select field_name, string_agg(id::text, ',')
from the_table
group by field_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use array_agg for this purpose,

```
SELECT field_name, array_agg(id)
FROM table
GROUP BY  field_name
```